# jQuery hover function, not working as expected with paragraph tags

Tags: jquery, html, css, onmouseover, onmouseout

I have `paragraph tags` within a `hover` div and each time the mouse enters a new paragraph the animation repeats.
Any ideas on what is wrong?

#### JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#container1a").mouseover(function() {
         $('#col1start').stop(true, true).fadeOut(800);
         $('#col1start').hide();
         $('#col1hover').stop(true, true).fadeIn(800);
      });
      $("#container1a").mouseout(function() {
         $('#col1hover').stop(true, true).fadeOut(800);
         $('#col1hover').hide();
         $('#col1start').stop(true, true).fadeIn(800);
      });
});
```

#### HTML

```
<div id="container1a">
    <div id="col1start">
        <p>text1</p>
        <p>text2</p>
        <p>text3></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `mouseover`/`mouseout` functions are being misused , see http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have function that handle both events at once, this code will give you a good start.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#container1a').hover(function() {

        $('#col1start').stop(true, true).fadeOut(800);
        $('#col1start').hide();
        $('#col1hover').stop(true, true).fadeIn(800);

    }, function() {

        $('#col1hover').stop(true, true).fadeOut(800);
        $('#col1hover').hide();
        $('#col1start').stop(true, true).fadeIn(800);
    }); 
});
```